# What does ~ do in LESS CSS?

Tags: less

I’ve seen the following code in some LESS CSS that I’m working on:

```
font: ~"@{baseFontSize} / @{baseLineHeight} @{baseFontFamilies}";
```

What does the `~` (tilde) do?

Comment: It's simple... the purpose of the ~ (tilde) is to strip the quotation marks from the output.

Comment: @JoeConlin: which quotation marks, and is that all it does?

Comment: The quotation marks that are wrapping the variables and yes, that is all that the tilde is doing in your example.

Comment: @JoeConlin If that were true, I could just remove the tilde *and* the quotation marks from the LESS source, and get the same CSS output.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained it better. In Less, quotation marks are used to tell Less to NOT compile but rather treat as a string. In your example, if you removed the quotes, Less would attempt to compile the line try to divide `@baseFontSize` by  `@baseLineHeight @baseFontFamilies`. Obviously, this will generate an error. So...we wrap it in quotes to tell Less to simply replace with variables and THEN remove the quotes from the output, hence the tilde. Hope that clears things up.